# How can we submit a configurable connector to OneLogin?

Tags: catalog, onelogin

We'd like to submit a configurable connector to OneLogin like Github's connector. (ref: the attached image)

However, I couldn't understand how to submit such the request though I've read https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/app-catalog

How can we allow users to edit custom values in Configuration tab?

[a screenshot of Github Connector's Configuration tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIqj9.jpg)

---

EDITED

I've understood what information to be submitted for a non-configurable connector by reading the document. However, nothing mentioned a configurable connector.

So I'd like to know:

- How to submit a configurable connector
- A format of a configurable connector request

Sorry for omitting the context. OneLogin's web page led me to ask them questions in StackOverflow so I've assumed those who will answer to my question are OneLogin's members.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The unique way to request a new connector to be added to the OneLogin catalog is by submitting a support ticket.